# Is it possible to log in facebook account without an alert warning if login alerts are already enabled?

Tags: security, password-protection

Recently someone of my friends tells me that he logged in my facebook account without knowing my password and without login alerts warning, he told me that he hacked my facebook account with some techniques. so my question: Is it possible to login into facebook account which facebook account owner allows unexpected logs alerts without him knowing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Technically, yes**

It is pretty close to *impossible* for him to have accessed your Facebook account without knowing your password via his own devices such as "hacking" your account. If anyone were to log into your account they would need your email and password, and this would often send you a code to your phone (2-factor authentication) or require you verify that it is definitely you logging in via an already-authorised device.

However, if he has gained physical access to one of your devices such as your phone, laptop or desktop PC where you are already logged in, he may be able to access your account from there. Because you're already logged in, he doesn't need the password. And because you've already verified it was you who logged in (because it was your device) then Facebook still thinks it is you logging in.

**My advice**

I would strongly advise you password protect each of your devices (your PC, phone, laptop, work or school account etc.) with a long yet memorable password or pin code. Don't pick anything that can easily be guessed such as "password" or "1234". Here's a [relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/936/).

Each time you leave your computer or stop using your phone, **lock it!**

**To be extra sure**

If you'd like that extra piece of mind that he isn't in your account, here's an extra couple of steps you can take.

First thing is first - link up your mobile phone to your account as a 2-factor authenticator. Whenever you log into your account from a new device, it will ask you to verify that device via a text message sent to your phone. This works per application too, meaning if you log into facebook on your phone via Chrome browser, it will be a different login to the Facebook app - so you'll need to verify twice!

Secondly, change your password if you think this person may know it. If there's even the slightest chance he might have your password or that it is easy to guess, change it immediately! The longer the better.

Next, you'll want to add email verification tokens using a PGP key. This encrypts your emails so that even if someone gains access to your account, they can't change the email and own it since they need to decrypt it with your key (you can Google this for more details on how to set it up). Also another [relevant article](https://www.facebook.com/notes/protect-the-graph/securing-email-communications-from-facebook/1611941762379302/) on setting this up. **Make sure this is working properly before you move to the next step!**

Finally, go into your Facebook settings and under your Active Sessions, click the "Log out everywhere" button. You will need to log into each device again and then hopefully use your phone to authenticate each login. This way you should pretty much guarantee that if you did accidently log into your account somewhere, it will be signed out next time this person tries to access it.

**Ensuring it doesn't get accessed again**

Finally, don't let your friends get access to your devices, and don't let them know your passwords. To prevent people from stealing your password, don't go clicking on any suspicious links or downloading any crapware.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer it helped me a lot, Can you explain how login alerts are going?, I will tell you what happened to me personally, he told me that he read some messages on my facebook messenger then he pasted it over my chat to prove that he can log into my account without me getting unexpected login facebook notification, one thing I want to know that if this person pretends to be a hacker to blow my mind.

Comment: No, he couldn't bypass that login mechanism unless he uses accesses your account by a device that you're already authorised on. So if you've logged into your account on a school computer then he used it afterwards, he'd be able to get your messages. I've also edited the post (added a few paragraphs) as to how you can be super-duper sure he isn't in your account. If he still tells you he has access, he is lying and pretending to be a hacker